# How to achieve this chapter style without using the memoir class?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

As `fncychap` has no such chapter style, and using the `memoir` class will cause a lot conflicts with my current settings (`book` class), how to make this style (perhaps using the `titlesec` package)?

Table of contents and Chapter style:

[image]
and
[image: I]

Here are my setting for chapters:

```
\usepackage[ ]{titlesec}  
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries }{\chaptertitlename\  \thechapter}{10pt}{\huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{40pt}{40pt}  % left, vertical, skip
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a way with `titlesec`; I also used `microtype` for spacing the small caps.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec,microtype}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
 {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
 {\makebox[\textwidth]{\titlerule[0.8ex]\quad\textls{\chaptername}\ \thechapter\quad\titlerule[0.8ex]}}
 {1ex}
 {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\centering\huge\textls[50]}
 [\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
 {\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
 {\makebox[\textwidth]{\titlerule[0.8ex]}}
 {1ex}
 {\titlerule\vspace{1ex}\centering\huge\textls[50]}
 [\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Contents}

\chapter{FETCH Automated Verification and Validation}

\end{document}
```

[image: numberless chapter]

[image: numbered chapter]

Comment: thanks! Could you please add the style for "Table of contents" and "List of figures", etc?

Comment: @KOF Done, it's quite easy, after all.

Comment: Well, how to make the chapter Title bold without `\scshape`?

Comment: @KOF Use `\bfseries` instead of `\scshape`; also remove `\lsstyle` and `\textls[50]`

Comment: It works but `Contents` and `List of Figures` remain un-bold, how come?  ---> I figured this out.

Comment: No need to define `\thicktitlerule`; you can use the built-in `\titlerule` and control the thickness with the optional argument: `\titlerule[.8ex]`.

Answer (score 12):

Another way using `titlesec` with `explicit` option:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\def\hrulefillthick{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule height3pt\hfill\kern0pt}

\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\hrulefillthick\hspace*{.5cm}\chaptertitlename\  \thechapter\hspace*{.5cm}\hrulefillthick}
{5pt}
{\titlerule\centering\huge#1}
[\titlerule]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
{\normalfont\normalsize\scshape}
{\hrulefillthick}
{5pt}
{\titlerule\centering\huge#1}
[\titlerule]

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{FETCH Automated Verification and Validation}
\lipsum[1-3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]